# why diagonal $S$ is a subsequence of $S_n?$

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin  theorem $7.23$

> If $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a pointwise bounded sequence of complex functions on a countable set $E$, then $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $(f_{n_k}(x))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges for each $x \in E$.

\begin{matrix}
   S_1: & f_{1, 1} & f_{1, 2} & \ldots \\
   S_2: & f_{2, 1} & f_{2, 2} & \ldots \\
   \vdots \\
   S_n: & f_{n, 1} & f_{n, 2} & \ldots \\
\end{matrix}

In the theorem  of the proof  Rudin say that   diagonal $S: f_{1,1},f_{2,2},......f_{n,n}...$ is a  subsequence of $S_n$

**My thinking** : Here  $S_n$ is a subsequence of $S_{n-1}$.  we are  starting from sequence $S_1$  so  by bolzano Wierstrass theorem we  can derived  another  sequence .similarly  we  can  derived $S_2$  from $S_1$,....$S_n$ from $S_{n-1}$

Therefore  by Bolzano Wierstrass theorem  we can derived $S_n$ from $S \implies S_n$ is a  subsequence of $S$

**My confusion** :why  diagonal $S$  is a subsequence  of $S_n?$

Comment: You haven’t define $f_{i,j}$ here.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews i think there is no need to define $f_{i,i}$ because   i'm talking about $S$ and $S_n$

Comment: $S_1=\{f_{1,n}\}$ is a subsequence of $f_n$ such that $f_{I,n}(x_1)$ converges; assuming $S_k$ has been constructed, $S_{k+1}=\{f_{k+1,n}\}$ is a subsequence of $S_k$ such that $f_{{k+1},n}(x_{k+1})$ converges (as $n\rightarrow\infty$. The diagonal $g_m=f_{m, m}$ is a sequence of $f$ because is for each $m$, there is $n_m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g_m=f_{n_m}$ , and $n_n<n_{m+1}$.

Comment: Except for possibly, say, the first $n$ terms, each $f_{k,k}$ where $k\ge n+1$ lies in $S_k, k\ge n+1$ and so appears in $S_n$.

Comment: At minimum, you need that $S_{i+1}$ is a subsequence of $S_i$ and $S_1$ is a subsequence of $f_1,f_2,\dots.$ It is certainly not true without these facts. @jasmine

Comment: When you say "$S_n$ is a subsequence of $S$," that is factually backwards. @jasmine

Comment: you  are right @ThomasAndrews        now I've understood it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, we enumerate $E=\{e_1,e_2,\dots\}.$ Then:

1. Define $S_1=\{f_{1,j}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ as a subsequence of $f_i$ such that $\lim_{j\to\infty}f_{1,j}(e_1)$ exists.
2. Given the $S_i$ defined, define $S_{i+1}=\{f_{i+1,j}\}_{j=1}^\infty$ as a subsequence of $S_i$ such that $\lim_{j\to\infty}f_{i+1,j}(e_{i+1})$ exists.

Then certainly, $\{f_{1,1},f_{2,2},\dots,\}$ is a sequence of functions from our original sequence, $\{f_1,f_2,\dots\}.$ The real question is whether we can get repeated $f_i$ or disordered $f_i$ in this sequence.

Let $m(i,j)$ be the index in the original series corresponding to $f_{i,j}.$ Then, since $S_{i+1}$ is a subsequence of $S_i,$ you get that $m(i+1,j)\geq m(i,j).$

You also have that $m(i,j+1)>m(i,j).$

To prove these two inequalities rigorously, you need to have a fairly rigorous definition of “subsequence,” but they are examples of results that are hopefully “obvious,” if you spend a moment thinking of them.

So $m(1,1),m(2,2),m(3,3),\dots$ is strictly increasing.

Then $f_{i,i}=f_{m(i,i)}$ is a subsequence of $f_1,f_2,\dots.$